# Do Rindler horizons evaporate?

Tags: thermodynamics, hawking-radiation, unruh-effect

It is thought that black holes radiate via Hawking radiation and consequently evaporate. Rindler horizons too emit radiation. Are they also thought to undergo a similar process of evaporation?

Comment: *It is known* Not really.  It would be more accurate to say "it is *thought*".  We have no real evidence of Hawking radiation.

Comment: agreed...editing it.

Comment: Horizons do not have to evaporate. Cosmological horizons also have finite temperatures and are not assumed to evaporate. Presumably Rindler horizons behave similarly.

Comment: @AndersSandberg That sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: To elaborate slightly on @AndersSandberg's comment: The Schwarzschild solution represents an eternal black hole (one that has always been present), and applying the usual derivation of Hawking radiation in this case shows that it absorbs radiation at the same rate that it emits radiation (both are the  same type of quantum effect), so it doesn't evaporate. It's in equilibrium. Same for Rindler horizons. A black hole that forms by collapse at some finite time in the past is different: it's not in equilibrium, and it theoretically would evaporate if it were truly isolated.

Comment: Radiation is emitted by matter. For example, the electromagnetic radiation (photons) is emitted by electrically charged particles. Vacuum does not emit radiation, it is a pseudo science, an artifact of a mathematical model taken beyond its limits of applicability. This also leads to a disagreement among observers on the number of quanta, which is not relative. For example, an observer killed by this radiation would still be alive in a frame of reference where this radiation does not exist. There is no Unruh or Hawking radiation, they are simply unphysical solutions of mathematical equations.

Comment: Furthermore, the Rindler spacetime is isomorphic to the Minkowski spacetime though a change of coordinates. Therefore, any change to the Rindler spacetime, such as the horizon "evaporation" would be equivalent to a change to the Minkowsi spacetime, such as a change of the speed of light, which is unphysical and illogical.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly thanks for your reply, I did not know about this.

Comment: @safesphere I do see the point, what I actually had in mind were a bunch of accelerating observers with a Rindler horizon, which decelerate as time progresses. For instance the observers can be charged particles that are accelerating under electric field but decelerate due to radiation back reaction. For such a bunch of observers would it be fair to say that in some sense the Rindler horizon is evaporating. Also I do appreciate your point about the observer that is killed by radiation but need to think through it carefully.